# React Native Newbie: When to switch screens, when to switch components

Tags: react-native, mobile

I'm developing my first mobile app (after a decade developing web), and I'm trying to figure out when to switch screens vs when to switch components within the same screen. Perhaps best explained by example:

I have a screen which, upon load, presents a very simple single-input form. Upon submitting data, a spinner presents until a simple results page loads. There are no common views between the form/spinner/results stages. I assume screen changes are an important part of memory management on mobile, but I have animated transitions that seem to animate slower when transitioning screens instead of individual views.

So: is there any standard conventions regarding when to swap out views vs when to navigate between screens?

Answer (score 4):

A common rule of thumb is that switching screens implies that you need some kind of navigation transition (a new screen slides in from right or the bottom).
If you don't need a navigation transition, then it's best to change the components inside that screen.

For your specific example, here is how I would go about it:
The Input form and the Spinner should both be components part of the same screen. The Input form is rendered first. Once the form is submitted, the Input component is replaced by the Spinner component.

Once the submission is completed, I would have an animated transition to the Results screen.

You could of course alternatively keep everything in the same screen and switch between all 3 components, but that is more of a UI/UX design issue and how you would want your app to behave.